# ASP.NET Membership Provider - Expose the salt

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership, salt, provider

### Background

We are using the ASPNET membership provider that stores member login information, along with MongoDB to store a secondary set of information.

Because MongoDB does not offer built-in encryption we have decided to encrypt some of the data before inserting it into the database using the member's salt that is in the ASPNET membership provider tables.

### Objective

**How would I go about exposing the salt so that it is accessible in code?** I cannot find any methods for this in the default provider classes.

### Alternative

Either that or could anybody suggest a better approach? One of the benefits of having the salt saved in a different place is to protect it from "interlopers".

Thanks,
Max.

Comment: If you choose to store the users password in hashed format the aspnet membership provider generates a salt and saves it in the database. I'm trying to make that salt accessible in code so I can use the same salt to encrypt the mongodb data

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, you can use the username, e-mail to salt.

```
public static string hashCalculator(string username, string password)//Use username as salt.
        {
            byte[] stringbytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(username.ToLower() + password);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(new SHA384Managed().ComputeHash(stringbytes));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I don't want to calculate a new salt, I want to use the existing one in the aspnet membership provider. In your example, if the user changes their username or password/email, we would have to re-encrypt all their data or it would be lost.

Comment: No problem if they change use the above to recalculate the new Hash and store it in the database, on login just compare the hashes.

Comment: This would involve storing the salt with the salted data which I don't want to do because it reduces security, or storing it in a new data field in the aspnet membership table which duplicates data. Would it not be easier to extend one of the aspnet membership classes and expose the existing salt?

Comment: AFAIK, ASP.NET Sql Membership provider stores a randomly generated salt in the database. So, salt is stored. Moreover salt is used for preventing breakins for people using same passwords. You always need to store salt.

Comment: Yes it does, and that is exactly the salt I want to use. What I am saying is, if the attacker breaks into the mongodb, they would have to be able to obtain the salt from the seperate ASPNET database to be able to easily decode the data from the mongodb. If we store a new salt in the mongodb they can do a brute force attack using the salt they already have...

Comment: RNG Crypto is used to generate the salt, if that helps.

Comment: I don't want to generate a new salt, I want to use the one the ASPNET membership provider generated when the user was created and stored in the database. The question is, how do I access it?

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to have a centralised service that does the authentication/authorisation for you, something akin to WIF?

Comment: It could be a nice solution but maybe overkill for what I am trying to achieve. After unsuccessfully trying to extend several aspnet membership classes to expose the existing salt I have decided the easiest way to tackle this problem is to, in the overridden "createuser" method of my custom membership provider, generate a new salt and save it as part of the users profile. Thanks for everybodies help. If anybody reading this does know a way to expose the existing salt in code then I'd still love to know :)